# Python kwargs filter extras

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a dictionary that I want to pass to matplotlib in order to plot a bar chart, this is simplifiying it but its a bit like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#This works fine:
plt.bar(x=range(3),height=[300,128,581],width=0.8,align='edge')

#This also works fine:
mydict = {'x':range(3),'height':[300,128,581],'width':0.8,'align':'edge'}
plt.bar(**mydict)

#But adding in something extra to my dictionary which might be there for other reasons screws it up:
mydict = {'x':range(3),'height':[300,128,581],'width':0.8,'align':'edge','fruit':'bananas'}
plt.bar(**mydict)

#/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in bar(x, height, width, bottom, #align, data, **kwargs)
#   2432     return gca().bar(
#   2433         x, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, align=align,
#-> 2434         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
#   2435 
#   2436
```

I have looked about and I can see that I can use `inspect` in order to get details of the function and the arguments. `inspect.signature(plt.bar)` gives:

> <Signature (x, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, *, align='center', data=None, **kwargs)>

This is useful in terms of removing things from my dictionary which aren't in this list but then I know from [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) that there are other optional kwargs such as **linewidth** and **log**.

I don't want to filter those out if they exist but I can't work out a way of listing possible kwargs along with the args.

Comment: **kwargs will take everything you throw at it in the dict, no need to remove non-supported kwargs - they will be ignored in the code. Otherwise - the docs is the place to check for the available optional arguments.

Comment: @buran that is what I had thought but the AttributeError I get further down in the code is ```'Rectangle' object has no property 'fruit'```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# #But adding in something extra to my dictionary which might be there for other reasons screws it up:
required = {'x':range(3),'height':[300,128,581]}
optional = {'width':0.8,'align':'edge','fruit':'bananas'}
mybar = plt.bar(**required)
for key, value in optional.items():
    try:
        setattr(mybar, key, value)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't used setattr() before but that definitely seems a good way to go about it.

Comment: That's one way of dealing with it. IMHO it should have been handled by `matplotlib`, so maybe there is some option that I don't know about. Would be interesting if someone comes with different solution.